# Смена параметров заказа при сохранении Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Появилась задача для определенной группы пользователей менять параметры заказа, для этого сделал обработчик в init.php, в котором по событию onSaleOrderSaved делаю проверку на принадлежность пользователя к группе и меняю параметры, однако для того, чтобы в дальнейшем менять параметры заказа уже из админки нужно сделать проверку на новизну заказа 
`$event->getParameter("IS_NEW")` 
однако с данной проверкой в дальнейшую часть функции процесс не заходит, без данной проверки код отрабатывает, дебажил и выводил значение параметра - там единица при новом заказе и Null при смене старых заказов через админку, вот сам код:

```
    
    function restriction(Bitrix\Main\Event $event) {
        if ($event->getParameter("IS_NEW")) {
            $order = $event->getParameter("ENTITY");
            $user = $order->getUserId();
            if (in_array(18, $arGroups = CUser::getUserGroup($user))) {
                $paymentCollection = $order->getPaymentCollection();
                foreach ($paymentCollection as $payment) {
                    $payment->delete();
                }
                $payment = $paymentCollection->createItem(\Bitrix\Sale\PaySystem\Manager::getObjectById(2)); //2 - ID нужной системы оплаты
                $payment->setField('SUM', $order->getPrice());
                $paymentCollection = $order->getPaymentCollection();
                $order->setField("USER_DESCRIPTION", "Комментарий для админов");
                $order->setField('STATUS_ID', 'N');
            }
        }
    }
```

В чем я ошибаюсь, может проверять нужно как-то иначе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$order->save() ;
```

В конце, вот в чем была ошибка, может кому-то поможет.